# HTML CSS .dropdown:hover trouble

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I have header that is moving when I scroll my page down. I have added several buttons to it, and they are moving with it. 
My problem is that my drop-button is showing its content when I am not hovering over the button itself.

My code:

```
/*------------------------------------dropdown menu start*/
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #B9B9B9;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    top: -18px;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    top: 18px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ffffff}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    color: #4d4d4d;
}
/*------------------------------------dropdown menu end*/
```

And a picture(black dot is a mouse location) : 
[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: can you put a live example with a code snipped?

Comment: http://codepen.io/vanzi/pen/PGzpPO

hope it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems run deep. I don't even really want to fix the entire menu because I'd basically be writing one from scratch and you can do that yourself, but what I will do is point out some issues with this to help  you find your way:

The core of your design:

```
<div class="header-cont">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="">
      <logotext>MyCompanyName</logotext>
      <button>Home</button>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Products</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Product 1</a>
          <a href="#">Product 2</a>
          <a href="#">Product 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button>Locations</button>
      <button>Contacts</button>
      <button>History</button>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Language</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Language 1</a>
          <a href="#">Language 2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

There are a number of things here I would never do:

1. `<logotext>` is not a valid HTML markup. You probably want a `<span class="logotext">` or something along those lines.
2. Your navigation menu is comprised of `<div>`s with `<button>`s and other `<div>`s with `<a>` tags in them. This is a bizarre and confusing way to organize a menu. You should consider using `<ul>` tags and order your sub menu with `<li>` instead.
3. The problem you are directly running into is caused by the fact that you have your home `<button>` element with a `left: 300px` on it that your `<div class="dropdown">` doesn't have.

A much easier and more logical way to organize a nav menu:

```
<ul id='menu'>
   <li><a href='#'>Planets</a>
     <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>Mercury</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Venus</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Earth</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'>Stars</a>
     <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>Sun </a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Betelgeuse</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Bellatrix</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'>Galaxies</a>
     <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>Milky Way </a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Andromeda</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Antennae</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I just got this from google and here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyelyn/4TmDu/) for it.

Comment: i understand, tnx. I'll try to write it this way. I found my mistake as you pointed out my left:300px was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/rrLyPV)

Your HTML should have a mark similar to this as per your CSS

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navItem"><a href="yourTarget">Home</a></div>
    <div class="navItem product-dropdown">
         <span>Products</span>
         <div class="dropdown-content">
              <ul>
                  <li>One</li>
                  <li>Two</li>
                  <li>Three</li>
              </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then as for styling something similar to this:

```
.dropdown-content{
    display:none;
}

.product-dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.navItem {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
 }
 li {
     list-style-type: none;
 }
```

Comment: when I do that all of my dropdowns disappear, but it solves hover on problem xD

Comment: Yeah my mistake, I see the `.dropdown-content { display: none;}` now.

Comment: Does the `:hover` work at all i.e. over the whole Navbar itself, or is it just stuck open?

Comment: it works fine when i hover over the button, but it is also showing when I hover over the header a bit left of the button it's self. In the pic my mouse is left of "Home" but my "Products" is showing drop list.

Comment: With that, I would say that your `div` with class `.dropdown` has both your "Home button" as well as your "Products" nested within. That would give it that effect or characteristic.

Comment: yes when I move it out of mu header class it works fine. But how can I make it so that I can leave  both of them in there? Because I want my buttons moving with header. Btw I am just learning html.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit, take a look now. I will add to this in more detail as well, give me a minute.

Comment: As you are learning the ways, this site as well as [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) will help you through it all. W3 is meant to be the "standards" and you will find any and all applicable HTML tags as well as CSS properties with live examples to help you through your work.